# strcpy behaving differently if destination string is uninitialized

Tags: c, string, huffman-code

I'm working in C trying to create a huffman decoder.  This piece of code only works if codearray comes in uninitialized, otherwise it gives me a segmentation fault.  However, valgrind complains that codearray is uninitialized if I do it that way.  I went through it with ddd and the segmentaion fault happens once strcpy is called and I cannot figure out why.

```
void printtree_inorder(node* n,char* code,char* letarray,char** codearray)
{
    if (n == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    static int counter=0;
    appenddigit(code,'0');
    printtree_inorder(n -> left,code,letarray,codearray);
    remdigit(code);
    if (n->let!='\0') {
       letarray[counter]=n->let;
       strcpy(codearray[counter],code);
       counter++;
    }
    appenddigit(code,'1');
    printtree_inorder(n -> right,code,letarray,codearray);
    remdigit(code);
}
```

Here is the calling function:

```
char code[100]={'\0'};
char** codearray=(char**)malloc(numchars*sizeof(char*));
for (i=0;i<numchars;i++) {
    codearray[i]=(char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
}


char* letarray=(char*)malloc((numchars+1)*sizeof(char));
letarray[0]='\0';

printtree_inorder(root,code,letarray,codearray);
```

Comment: Can you show the code that does the allocations and calls this function

Comment: What do appenddigit and remdigit do?

Comment: what is the value of numchars? also why is your counter declared static?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i=0;i<numchars;i++) {
    codearray[i]=(char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
}
```

this is the code you talking about? it is not really initialization code, it is making room for data code.

```
char** codearray=(char**)malloc(numchars*sizeof(char*));
```

just creates you an array of char *, but they do not point to any valid memory.
so, your "initialization code" just makes sure, that your memory is created correcly.

the other thing what really scares me is, that your counter variable is static.
calling

```
printtree_inorder(root,code,letarray,codearray);
printtree_inorder(root,code,letarray,codearray);
```

will also end in a segmentation fault, since counter will be > then numchars when you call it a second time (from outside).
so, lets rewrite your code a bit and make it more safe

```
char* code = (char *)malloc(numchars + 1);
memset(code, 0, numchars + 1);

char* letarray = (char *)malloc(numchars + 1);
memset(letarray, 0, numchars + 1);

char** codearray = (char **)malloc(numchars * sizeof(char *));
memset(codearray, 0, numchars * sizeof(char *));

printtree_inorder(root, code, letarray, codearray, 0);

free(code);
// do not forget the free the other allocations later as well as


void printtree_inorder(node* n,char* code,char* letarray,char** codearray, int counter)
{
    if (n == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    appenddigit(code,'0');
    printtree_inorder(n -> left,code,letarray,codearray, counter);
    remdigit(code);
    if (n->let!='\0') 
    {
       letarray[counter] = n->let;
       codearray[counter] = strdup(code);
       ++counter;
    }
    appenddigit(code,'1');
    printtree_inorder(n -> right,code,letarray,codearray, counter);
    remdigit(code);
}
```

Comment: this seems to work but later when I call strcmp("string",codearray[i]) it crashes with a segmentation fault

Comment: @Free_D, are you positive that i is < then numchars?, that the "string" is initialized properly (i am guessing, that "string" is not really "string", but some other variable), and that you did not free the codearray memory in between?

Answer (score 0):

Probably in the "initialized" call the array isn't really correctly initialized at all, therefore the function crashes.

When "not initialized", the array probably contains values that (by chance) don't lead to a segmentation fault, depending on what the program has done previously with the memory that ends up being used for `codearray`.

The function tries to copy a string to wherever `codearray[counter]` points to:

```
strcpy(codearray[counter],code);
```

In the function call you show this `codearray[counter]` is a random value since only the array was malloc'ed, but the elements weren't initialized to any specific values. `strcpy()` then tries to write to that random memory address.

You have to allocate memory for the copy of the string, for example by using `strdup()` instead of `strcpy()`.

Comment: I've never heard of strdup but would I use it like this? codearray[counter]=strdup(code,100)?

Comment: See for example: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/strdup.html

Comment: the elements of the array are allocated